How to create an SVG element in TypeScript?
Consider this TypeScript:
let text: SVGTextElement = document.createElement('text');

This gives me a warning:

TS2322: Type HTMLElement is not assignable to type SVGTextElement

How can I programmatically create an SVG element typed as SVGTextElement?

The createElement creates an HTML element by default, so I think you can use createElementNS method that allows you to create elements in a specific XML namespace.
Let me provide sample code:
let text: SVGTextElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");

Hope it helps you.
